# Using Euclidan Distance to intialize centroid of K-Means

Tags: algorithms, cluster

I need to initialize centroid of **K-Means** using **Euclidan distance**. Is it possible? If so how the algorithm should be? I have been stuck for a while and couldn't figure it out.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You dont initialize k-means using Euclidean distance. There are a range of [initialization methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Initialization_methods).

The most intuitive is selecting random instances from your data and initializing there. That way each cluster in your first assignment step has at least one instance. The assignment step is where you apply a distance measure, like euclidean distance.

Comment: So it is not possible to do this? Just asking

Comment: What did you want to measure the euclidean distance from? You can place the centroids anywhere so for example you could randomly initialize them a set euclidean distance from the mean of the entire dataset.

Comment: It is not my decision to make actually. But if it is cannot be done I will talk to those who do.